# Layers wont show above basemap using OpenLayers 5 + OpenWeatherMap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using OpenLayers and OpenWeatherMap Api to load layers above the openlayers basemap. The basemap loads correctly but layers such as Precipitation and Temperature wont show above the basemap. I have checked that the values are passing correctly through the url

I have tried setting the opacity of the layers and changing the visible attribute to true for the layers but the issue remains

```
 var map = new ol.Map({ 
 target: 'map', 
 layers: [ 
 new ol.layer.Tile({ 
 source: new ol.source.OSM()
 })
 ],
 view: new ol.View({ 
 center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon,lat]), // i am getting lon and lat from json 
 zoom: 5 
 })

});

 var temp_over =  new ol.layer.Tile({
 source: new ol.source.XYZ({
 url: 'https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/5/' + lat +'/'+lon+'.png?appid='+appid,

 }),

});
    map.updateSize();
    map.addLayer(temp_over);
```

The layer of temperature should have loaded above the basemap but it doesn't load.

Comment: any update on this?